# Verificar usuário dentro do circle do Map e ativar um button

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e me deparei em uma lógica que não estou conseguindo resolver, se alguém puder dá uma força agradeceria muito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um destino que tem um circulo de range dele eu fiz ele com este código:

```
private void setDestino(Double latitude, Double longitude){
    latDestino = latitude;
    longDestino = longitude;
    LatLng destino = new LatLng(latDestino, longDestino);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destino).title  ("Destino entrega Depósito."));
    CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions().center(destino);
    circle.fillColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    circle.radius(30); //Em metros.
    map.addCircle(circle);
}
```

e tenho um marcador de um usuário que está indo para esse destino, ele está sendo atualizado pegando as informações de localização do celular:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    if(l != null){
        latitude = l.getLatitude();
        longitude = l.getLongitude();
        LatLng usuario= new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        LatLng destino = new LatLng(latDestino, longDestino);
        map.clear();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(usuario).title("Usuário"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(usuario));
        setDestino(latDestino, longDestino);
        adicionaPolyline(map, mastertrack, destino);
    }
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude()), 20));

}
```

A lógica que me falta é, quando o usuário estiver fora do circulo um button ficará desativado, quando eu clico no circulo do destino eu verifico se o marcador do usuário está dentro do circulo e ativo o button.

Se alguém souber e puder me esclarecer essa lógica será de um grande favor. Obrigado.

Comment: Veja [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

Comment: Matematicamente falando: você sabe as coordenadas do centro do círculo e as coordenadas do usuário. Ele está dentro do círculo se a distância dele ao centro for menor ou igual ao raio do círculo.